# Joins or intersects in SOQL

Tags: soql

I don't have relation between user and contact object, but they are related by data.
id field in both of them is joinable.

```
Select Id, email, Firstname, lastname from contact c where c.Id IN (select u.Id from user u)
```

which generates the following error

[image: Select Id, email, Firstname, lastname from contact c where c.Id IN (select u.Id from user u)]

Answer (score 3):

A Contact Id is not a User Id. You probably mean:

```
SELECT Email, FirstName, LastName 
FROM Contact 
WHERE Id IN (SELECT ContactId FROM User)
```

The aliases are not necessary, like in SQL when referring to the same object.